# Can't start django app with daphne

Tags: django, heroku

I was going through a [tutorial](https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django) on Django Channels until I came across the command that should start my app `daphne apps.base.asgi:channel_layer -p 8000`.What could be the reason my django app doesn't start when running it in terminal. It doesn't show any errors, when I press Enter it just goes to new line without running the command.

Comment: Are you running workers too?

Comment: Yes, but i thought i was supposed to start the app first and then call the runnworker command

Comment: And when you try using `runserver` what is the output?

Comment: `2017-09-21 11:43:26,844 - ERROR - server - Error trying to receive messages: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.`
I get this message over and over again

Comment: Is that locally or on Heroku?

Comment: It's run locally

Answer (score 0):

Channel is not able to connect to redis. Start local redis server and try